# form rendering through tpl file

Tags: 6, forms, theming

I want to render drupal 6 form through tpl file.
for that 
1. I have written mytheme_theme in template.php file and there I have define my template forms arguments and path for tpl file.

1. I have written tpl file
2. in form function at the end I have called theme by `'#theme' => 'my_template'`

doing all these thing my from is rendering through tpl but now its not going into `submit_hander()` and validation.

can any one help me these? I am not getting what's wrong in these.

see in my template.php contain:

```
function cs_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $hooks = zen_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path);
  // Add your theme hooks like this:
  /*
  $hooks['hook_name_here'] = array( // Details go here );
  */

  // @TODO: Needs detailed comments. Patches welcome!

  $hooks['my_theme_example'] = array(
                  'arguments' => array(
                  'order' => null, 
                  ),
                  'render element' => 'form',
                 'template' => 'mymodule_template',
                 'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'theme_name') . '/templates',
              );

  return $hooks;
}
```

In these way I have printed all the form fields
in my .tpl file is:

```
   <?php print drupal_render($variables['order']['logo']);?>
```

Comment: Change theme hook definition for the form in hook_registry_alter().

Comment: can u plez explain in more detail?

Comment: Zz.. So hard to help you) Do you have '<form ' . $action . ' accept-charset="UTF-8" method="' . $element['#method'] . '" id="' . $element['#id'] . '"' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . "> in your template?

Comment: Can we attach files here so that you can view my code and then you can help me

Answer (score -1):

You need rewrite 'form' like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_registry_alter().
 */
function mymodule_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $form_registry = &$theme_registry['form'];
  $form_registry['function'] = 'mymodule_form_theme';
}
function mymodule_form_theme($element) {
  // I'm not sure that $element has 'from_id' but you could pass it if you need.
  if ($element['form_id'] == 'yours_form_id') {
    return theme_form($element);
  }
  // Else return what you need I guess that better to use hook_theme()
  // and then call theme() function.
}
```

Look at `theme_form()` to understand what variables need to pass in form tag.
I don't understand why do you need this. What is the reason to use template file?

Comment: thanks for reply.
i have written hook_theme() in .module file. but thn also its going into submit hander.
is anything miss by me?

Comment: Describe what you need at the end. Do you need simple form without Drupal Form API? Or you need change submit handler? Or what else?

Comment: I have created custom form and for that I have written submit_handler() and validation, the form was working fine without writing anything in tpl, template file. but there is requirement that form should be render through template file, so I have done all thing which mention above but now its not going into submit_handler(). I want the form should go into submit_handler() and the form should render through template.

Comment: Show your template file in your question. Also, do you get form content throw drupal_get_form() function?

Comment: I am getting form content through tpl file but only prob is that it is not going in submit_handler()

Comment: Show the template file, content of file with tpl! I think the problem is that you don't add in html required form params.

Comment: hi. see my tpl file sample. like wise i m printing all the form fields

Comment: -1 This is not the standard way of [overriding themable output](https://www.drupal.org/node/341628).

Comment: This is not standard way but there is no standard way to override theme_hook with 'function' param not for all theme('key').